# Cycle 2 não funciona

Tags: jquery

Já consegui fazer um slyde com pagers, mas eu tive que invocar a função cycle. Digo isso porque no site oficial fala que não precisa de nenhuma linha de código, tudo é feito por marcação, mas na verdade não foi assim, agora voltando ao assunto, vou deixar o código do carousel vertical:

```
<div id="t2"class="slideshow vertical" data-cycle-carousel-vertical=true 
data-cycle-carousel-visible=4>
    <img src="01.jpg" width="80" height="80">
    <img src="02.jpg" width="80" height="80">
    <img src="03.jpg" width="80" height="80">
    <img src="04.jpg" width="80" height="80">
    <img src="05.jpg" width="80" height="80">
    <img src="06.jpg" width="80" height="80">
    <img src="07.jpg" width="80" height="80">
    <img src="08.jpg" width="80" height="80">
</div>
```

---

```
$(function() 
{
    $('#t2').cycle();
});
```

Comment: Você não atribuiu a classe que a documentação recomenda para que seja iniciado o carrossel automaticamente. A classe indicada é `cycle-slideshow`. Veja [o exemplo dado em marcação para inicio automatico](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/basic.php)

Comment: Tá, esse slide show padrão funciona, até mesmo sem adicionar cycle-slideshow, mas eu adicionei a classe aqui e não mudou nada, só fica no slide show padrão. Carousel vertical que é bom nada.

Comment: Em relação ao exemplo dado do [carousel vertical na documentação](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php#vertical) faltam-lhe alguns atributos. Pessoalmente eu começava por colocar todos, para começar num exemplo igual ao da documentação e que funciona. Depois a partir dai pode ir retirando e alterando atributo a atributo até ver em que ponto quebra e qual o atributo que lhe está a fazer deixar de funcionar.

Comment: Na documentação do sile o slide que eu preciso montar não exige essa classe que você falou, e não adianta, eu posso fazer do jeito que tá no site que não vai. Só funciona o slide básico.